# How can I toggle the presence of a Toolbar above a Tab Bar inside a Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I have 3 bars:

1) A Navigation Bar at the top with a button "Edit"

2) A Tab Bar that is used to switch between View Controllers

3) A Toolbar that I would like to appear directly above the Tab Bar when the "Edit" button is tapped. (And hidden when "Edit" is tapped again.)

Does anybody have any idea how to go about doing this? Is there a way to manipulate constraints programmatically to achieve this?

Comment: why you want to manipulate constraint, just make the hidden property `true`. something like - `objToolBar.hidden = YES` to hide and NO to show it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link your edit button to an IBAction (or do it programmatically).
Then within it you can simply use the `hidden` property of the toolbar in order to make it appear or to hide it.

It should look like this :

```
@IBAction func yourButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.yourToolbar.hidden = !self.yourToolbar.hidden
}
```